# Message time to write to S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, boto3

Writing to S3 (and perhaps all operations) using [boto3](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object) takes about 300ms, even for a tiny amount of data on an EC2 instance.

Profiling shows that time is dominated by reading, e.g., `_SSLSocket.read()` - possibly when establishing the secure connection or simply for the server to respond.

Is there any way to decrease the operation time? Perhaps there is a lower-level API call that could be used?

```
%prun -s time client.put_object(Bucket='MDtemp', Key='temporary2', Body=b'Hello')



   2197 function calls (2188 primitive calls) in 0.094 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.045    0.045    0.045    0.045 {built-in method select}
       26    0.045    0.002    0.045    0.002 {method 'read' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'write' of '_ssl._SSLSocket' objects}
       26    0.000    0.000    0.045    0.002 socket.py:364(readinto)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 socket.py:200(makefile)
       26    0.000    0.000    0.045    0.002 ssl.py:737(recv_into)
       27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 message.py:463(get)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 awsrequest.py:195(_handle_expect_response)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'readline' of '_io._IOBase' objects}
      8/6    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 hooks.py:175(_emit)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 socket.py:352(__init__)
      245    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'lower' of 'str' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.092    0.092 connectionpool.py:317(_make_request)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.093    0.093 sessions.py:539(send)
       26    0.000    0.000    0.045    0.002 ssl.py:611(read)
        3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _collections_abc.py:575(update)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.045    0.006 {method 'readline' of '_io.BufferedReader' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 feedparser.py:217(_parsegen)
      150    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 parsers.py:639(_parse_non_payload_attrs)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 client.py:1092(putheader)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 feedparser.py:470(_parse_headers)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 client.py:284(parse_headers)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 parse.py:286(urlparse)
       23    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 parse.py:98(_coerce_args)
       27    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 socket.py:405(readable)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.094    0.094 {built-in method exec}
       40    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 _policybase.py:269(_sanitize_header)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.046    0.046 awsrequest.py:146(_send_output)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 auth.py:532(canonical_standard_headers)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.045    0.045 client.py:347(_read_status)
        ...
```

Comment: The big time eater is going to be the SSL handshake.  In other environments (not a python person, here) HTTP keep-alives helped me amortize this setup cost across multiple requests by reusing connections... but from inside EC2 within the same region as S3 300ms still seems a little sluggish.  I'll see if I have something to compare to, which may help rule S3 itself in or out as a significant contributor.  I know I can send and receive 1000 `HEAD` requests in ~2 seconds with one of the tools I've written using async I/O, but now I don't remember whether it's HTTPS.

Comment: Is your instance in the same region as the bucket?  It turns out the time for the SSL handshake is negligible within a region because the round-trip time is so low (ping time < 0.2ms with an elastic IP).  Cross-region, testing us-west-2 (client) to us-east-1 (bucket) I get a ~380ms on the first request (easily attributable to the SSL negotiation), and 90ms for the 2nd request on a kept-alive connection.

Comment: So we must be making a new connection each time. How do you establish a kept-alive connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

s3fs now supports [asynchronous operations](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/pull/336) using the `aiobotocore` library. This reuses connections and enables concurrency, so that the waiting time can be amortised over many calls, leading to much lower average latency. The total time for a single call is not much affected, if the SSL connection has not already been established.

Answer (score 0):

you CAN accomplish this using BASH, you'll have to call-out to an external app such as the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI).

visit: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/

Comment: Takes hundreds of ms also

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using s3cmd? It is a command line tool for linux, which is very effective, but I never measured its performance.

Comment: Also takes ~300ms (and that's with encryption off)

Comment: If you are not interested in high redundancy, you can manually set s3cmd to use only a single region (the closest one to you). Maybe that will shave a few ms in that time.

Comment: boto3 also allows you to specify the region, as does the aws cli.